# how to change background to selected image by selecting image in Jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to change my background image by clicking on thumbs image .. I have these codes .. load page is working correctly .. but when I click on thumb image my background does not change . please help 
I have this code in my page load . This code load an image in page load :

```
$(function() {
                //the loading image
                var $loader     = $('#st_loading');
                //the ul element 
                var $list       = $('#st_nav');
                //the current image being shown
                var $currImage  = $('#st_main').children('img:first');

                //let's load the current image 
                //and just then display the navigation menu
                $('<img>').load(function(){
                    $loader.hide();
                    $currImage.fadeIn(3000);
                    //slide out the menu
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $list.animate({'left':'0px'},500);
                    },
                    1000);
                }).attr('src',$currImage.attr('src'));
```

I want to change my background to selected image by selecting image :

```
//clicking on a thumb, replaces the large image
                $list.find('.sc_menu a').bind('click',function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $loader.show();
                    $('<img class="st_preview"/>').load(function(){
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img:first');
                        $this.insertBefore($currImage);
                        $loader.hide();
                        $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }).attr('src',$this.attr('alt'));
                }).bind('mouseenter',function(){
                    $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'1'});
                }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'0.7'});
                });
```

And this is my html code :

```
<body>

        <div id="st_main" class="st_main">
            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" class="st_preview" style="display:none;"/>
            <a class="back" href="#"><< back to Codrops</a>
            <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Brand 1</a>
                    <div class="sc_menu_wrapper">
                        <div class="sc_menu">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg"/></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg"/></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg"/></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg"/></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg"/></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg"/></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg"/></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('<img class="st_preview"/>').load(function(){
        var $newimg         = $(this);
        var $currImage      = $('#st_preview').children('img:first');
        $newimg.insertBefore($currImage);
        $loader.hide();
        $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){$(this).remove();});
    }).attr('src',$e_next.find('img').attr('alt'));
}
```

Comment: I think you're following the same tutorial if so you can have a view at this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/09/08/full-page-image-gallery/

Comment: I think problem is in '$list.find('.sc_menu a').bind('click',function()' part .

Comment: can you just drop a fiddle so that it will be more clear to view the problem.

Comment: I use two tympanus jquery tutorial to create a site .. for this reason I can't make sync between theme ..

Answer (score 0):

try changing  `$('<img class="st_preview"/>').load` to `$('img.st_preview').load`

The first one creates a new `img` dom object in memory and assigns the `src`, where as the second one finds your existing `st_preview` and changes its `attr`